# Redirect a virtual directory in IIS / Azure

Tags: http, azure, redirect, iis, azure-web-app-service

I currently have two `asp.net mvc` websites hosted on a single azure web service:
 - `domain.com/`
 - `domain.com/app/`

I have a virtual directory `/app`

I want to now combing the two sites functionalities into one, and then host it in the root directory.  However I don't want to break existing links out there.

How can I make it so that any request to `domain.com/app/anything' gets redirected to 'domain.com/anything'

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Comment: Nope, Placing an empty webcofig with the rewrite module ended up in cannot load assemblies elmah exception. I tried adding the rule to a complete website, but after adding the rule, I just get a not found error.

Comment: Could you provide your web.config and the detailed error message for us to locate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't clarify what technology you are using for your websites.
What you basically need is URL rewrite module.
You can deploy in your web.config something like this:

```html
<rewrite>
  <rules>
          <rule name="RedirectToRoot" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^app/(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
          </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: So do I need to delete all files in `/app` directory and then simply just past a `web.config` in the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario, you could leverage URL Rewrite Module to achieve your purpose. In order to do this, you need to migrate the functionalities of your website under the virtual directory into the root website, then configure the URL rewrite module under the `system.webServer` section of your root web.config. Also, you need to remove all the files under the virtual directory when you deployed your root website. For more details about URL Rewrite Module, you could refer to [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) and [Using the URL Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).